# Reprogramming bootloader on Embedian MXM-8310 single board computer

Tags: embedded

I accidentally wiped the bootloader on one of our Embedian MXM-8310 single board computers, and would like to know how to restore it... The internet isn't proving very useful here.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices, you can send the board back to Embedian and they'll reprogram it for you or reprogram it with JTAG.

The easiest way to reprogram with JTAG is if you have the development board, as it has a JTAG header, but perhaps you are able to solder a JTAG onto the COM ([pin details](http://www.embedian.com/wiki/index.php/Pxa320_based_com)).

You'll need a JTAG cable and software that is able to program the Samsung NAND chip in 128K blocks. The cheapest option is to buy a OpenOCD compatible JTAG cable like the [usb-tiny-h](http://www.olimex.com/dev/arm-usb-tiny-h.html).